# $N + 2N + 3N +\dotsb$ series?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been trying to figure this out but no luck yet.

What is the general formula for the sum
$N + 2N + 3N + 4N +\dotsb$?

Could it be equal to something like

$$N + 2N +3N + ..... + xN = \frac{xN(N+1)}{2}.$$

where $x$ is an integer .

For example when $N = 2$ and $x = 5$ you would get

$$2 + 2\cdot2 + 3\cdot2 + 4\cdot2 + 5\cdot2 = 30.$$

Please link me to sources for more explanation. Thanks

Comment: Try factorizing $N$.

Comment: If you know how to sum the first $x$ integers, just multiply that by $N$. *The distributive property at work.*

Comment: somebody said it should be like the one I posted and another said it should be 0n + 1n + 2n + ... + (n-1)n = (0+1+2+...+n-1)n = n(n-1)n/2 ... just confused!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first few lines are very misleading. It sounds like you are saying this thing is finite.

Let $n, k \in \mathbb N$. Then
$$n+2n+3n+\dotsb+kn = n(1+2+\dotsb+k)$$
by the distributive law.
Moreover, the sum
$$1+2+\dotsb+k$$ is very well known, I think you understand that
$$1+2+\dotsb+k = \frac{k(k+1)}{2}.$$
Thus,
$$n+2n+\dotsb+kn = n(1+\dotsb+k) = n\frac{k(k+1)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 3):

$$N + 2N +3N + ..... + xN = N(1+2+\cdots+x) = N \frac{x(x+1)}{2}$$
For your example, we get 
$$2 \frac{5(5+1)}{2} = 5(6) = 30$$